# Ajaxsubmit function don't give me success message but image get uploaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, image-uploading

Following is the script on change from files input type please have a look. Please share me how i can display response.

```
$('#files').change(function(){        

    var url = $(this).val();
    var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    var ajaximgupload="1";
    if (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg") 
    {           
         $("#myForm").ajaxSubmit({
             url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'floats','action'=>'index'))?>',
             data: ({attachement:url}),
             dataType: "text/html",
             cache: false,
             type: "post",
             success: function(response) {                  
                 alert(response);
                $("#target").attr("src","/uploads/attachement/"+response);
             },
             resetForm: true
         });

    } else {  alert("Invalid Image Format"); return false;}
});
```

Comment: Does the `AJAX` function get invoked successfully? You can check this using tools like fiddler.  If so, what is `response`? Is it a JavaScript object or `undefined`?

Comment: Nothing will be display i have used http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ plugin for it. Please suggest if any other.

Comment: Is the response being alerted? What is there if it is? I suspect the dataType for the return may not be correct.

Comment: Used ajaxForm instead of ajaxSubmit and it's works Great for me. find out self solution.